# 'text-decoration-line: underline ' not working

Tags: html, css

In css file, I have given the code to underline my text using,
text-decoration-line: underline
But it's not working.
It's not even working for line-through as well.
I used this style for h1 tag and I gave no id or class for h1 tag.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: share your code

Comment: it is fine you don't need the code because it is a wrong type of style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `text-decoration` just like this:

```
.hi {
text-decoration: underline;
}
<h1 class="hi" >
Hi guys
</h1>
```